# Meaning of <amount of money> + から

Tags: particle-から

I recently came across a [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ziX1oQRiA3w) about a person going to a convenience store.

At some point in the song, the character makes a 220 yen purchase and tries to annoy the cashier by giving 10,000 yen, expecting change. She (the character) says this:

> 一万円から！

Both the subtitles and every lyrics page I find translate this as "here's 10,000 yen". Being that から means "from" after a noun, I have no idea how they got that translation, and I can't find any other definitions where this would make sense.

Comment: I think it would be similar to saying, "Can you take the amount you need **from this 10,000 yen** and give the rest back?"

Comment: When you say, "She says this", is the **she** the cashier or the character?

Comment: She is the character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite simply, that just means **"Out of a 10,000-yen bill, (please)!"**.

She is demanding her change as meanly as the clerks are treating her.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, the shop person was requested to make change from 10000yen to 220yen.

'から' means starting point. In this case, starting point is 10000yen and ending point is 220yen.

> 東海道は、江戸の日本橋から始まり、京都・三条大橋に至る街道である。

Tohkaidou was a road which connected Nipponbashi, Edo to Sanjyo bridge in Kyoto.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the best translation for から is with.

It means "(paying) with 10.000yens bill". In Japan people often try to use their coins especially at the convenient store so the cashier will wait to see if you don't have any coins to round it up. That's why people say out loud 'i'll pay with this amount', so the cashier won't wait.

More proper way, also often used : 一万円からで (xx円からで)